# facing upgrade and update issues

Tags: upgrade, updates

```
Err:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Taking data from your question (*link in a web browser*) I get to https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager which clearly shows it doesn't support releases after 2021..   PPA's (*Personal Package Archives*) are 3rd party sources, so the only security checks are those that you perform yourself - did you look before adding it?  I'd not have added something that was last looked at 95 weeks ago, well before your actual system was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a PPA you are using is not compatible with the new version.

If you are using the software updater to do the upgrade (on desktop ubuntu) then it should guide you through what to do when you encounter this eg ppa-purge, not just by removing the ppa or packages.

It's generally recommended to remove software from PPAs prior to an upgrade, or at the minimum, verify with the PPA maintainer whether it is compatible with the new ubuntu version.

Comment: sorry im a noob can you explain using simpler terms

Comment: You've installed some third party software from webupd8 team which appears to have a website [here](http://www.webupd8.org/).  The software was installed using one or more PPAs which is a way to add or replace software on your ubuntu install without using ubuntu's own software repositories.  These don't necessarily always fail during an update, but in this case, this one is failing. Are you updating *from* kinetic?  Unless you can use ppa-purge to remove this all you may need to get support about this from web upd8 people

Comment: There are various instructions for using ppa-purge here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed
I don't think just removing the repository would be sufficient in this case.

Comment: thank you sir/ma'am that was very helpful